# Infinite dimensional euclidian space with the product topology metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ be the space of real sequenes with the product topology.
Is $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ metrizable?

Comment: It seems to me that you land at $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$, which has the $\ell^1$-Norm and its induced metric:
$$d(a,b) = \Vert a-b \Vert_{\ell^1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n - b_n|$$

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Well, do you know about the $\ell^p(\mathbb N)$-spaces?

Comment: It seems to me the topology you get from this metric is finer. So if you could show me how you get that their equivalent I would be grateful

Comment: I just had this as an intuitive idea and unfortunately I don't have the time to prove it now, sorry. // Ah, sorry. The set of sequences $\delta_a := (a, 0, 0, \ldots)$ with $a\in(0,1)$ is open in $\ell^1$ but not open in the product topology, so nevermind.

Comment: @AlexR Not all sequence of real numbers lie in $\ell^1$, so it is easier than that.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker See my further comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** As $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $(0 , 2^{-n} )$ for all $n \geq 1$, it follows that $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ (with the product topology) would be homoemorphic to $Y =\prod_{i=1}^\infty ( 0 , 2^{-n} )$.  Can you think of a natural candidate for a metric on $Y$?